# Remove seek from default receiver dialog

Tags: google-cast

I am casting ad bumpered content. The ads should not be skippable.

When casting the cast dialog has a progress bar which means the ads can be skipped.

Is it possible to remove the media player controls from the chromecast dialog box?

Comment: Are you using the CAF sender and receiver?

Comment: no, I'm using the cast SDK version 3

Comment: We highly recommend that you move to CAF. It has built-in support for ads.